# return a value without return type declaration in template, is this a typo?

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

I am watching the talk [Modern Template Metaprogramming](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Am2is2QCvxY) by Walter E. Brown. At 54:40 a code is given as below

```
template<class T, T v>
struct integral_constant{
  static constexpr T value = v;
   constexpr  operator T() const noexcept { return value; } // what does this mean?
   constexpr T operator T() const noexcept { return value; }
};
```

My question is what does this line mean
`constexpr  operator T() const noexcept { return value; }`, why there is no return type but it is still returning `value`? Is this a typo?

Comment: It's a conversion function. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator

Comment: The second line is actually `constexpr T operator ()() const noexcept { return value; }`, which is a function call operator.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I overlooked the slide.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the second operator line is wrong and can be deleted completely.

A type operator like eg. `operator int()` is executed
when the object is casted or implicitly converted to the type:

```
MyClass myObject;
int i = myObject; // here operator int() is used.
```

Naturally, `operator int()` has to return `int`. It´s not necessary or allowed to write a specific return type for such operators. In your case, it´s not `int` of `float` or anything specific, but the template type, but it´s the same idea.

Aside from the return type problem, the second operator line defines the same operator with same parameters again, there can´t be multiple functions with same name and parameters.

And after the whole `struct`, a semicolon is missing.

After fixing these problems, it compiles: http://ideone.com/Hvrex5

Comment: sorry, the semicolon for `struct` is fixed.

Comment: The second line in the talk is correct. The OP transcribed it wrong. And it's called a "conversion function", not a "type operator".

Comment: I watched it now, yes. OP: With the correct line, you can keep both operators, the first being the type op like explained here and the second is a normal op with return type like usual.

Comment: @T.C. `And it's called...` How about "user-defined type-cast-or-implicit-conversion operator class method (member function)"? Really now...

Comment: [class.conv.fct]/p1. That's what the standard calls it.

Answer (score 3):

The first one is not a typo. That syntax is used to provide conversion from an object of the class to another type.

The return type is `T`

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator for more info.

The `consexpr` qualifier indicates to the compiler that return value of the member function can be determined at compile time if the object on which it is invoked is also `constexpr` qualified.

The second one is not a legal statement.